# Delete items from a dict list containing google drive flies

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, google-drive-api

I need to delete some items from a dict list. This list is produced by a call to Google Drive Rest Api.

I've tried several code samples but I can't make it work. I'm a Python newbie.

```
#this is the Google Api call
theFiles = drive_service.files().list(fields="files(id,name,modifiedTime, size, fileExtension)").execute()

#here I am trying to iterate the results and delete all items that refer to a "temp" file:

for k, v in theFiles.items():
    if v[4]=="tmp":
        del theFiles[k]
```

I was expecting that records containing a "tmp" extension would be deleted from this list, however I can't make it work.

I thought that `v[4]` whould refer to the "fileExtension" field of the dictionary. However, when I debug I see that `v[4]` contains the whole item, for example:

```
{'fileExtension': 'docx', 'id': '1u7zrCm3waGr9CiEmPl...F2acV7NvC', 'modifiedTime': '2019-05-03T18:59:19.000Z', 'name': '~$ LENGUA PROG.docx', 'size': '162'}
```

Please help me understand how to write the right code to delete items with the ".tmp" extension.

Comment: In addition, if I use another condition that allows me to delete some items, I get "RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration".

Comment: You are iterating over something you are changing a better way of doing this would be a dictionary comprehension `{k:v for k,v in theFiles.items() if v[4] != "tmp"}`

Comment: Also can you post how your full dictionary looks because I'm confused on the layout and without it I can't properly answer your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for your help, that gave me a clue on how to do this.
After some research I ended up using comprehension:

```
dicFiles[:]  = [x for x in dicFiles if x['name'].endswith('.tmp')]
```

That does the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function to generate the index along with the elements of the sequence you are looping over. I assume that items is similar to this:

```
items = [{'fileExtension': 'docx', 'id': '1u7zrCm3waGr9CiEmPl...F2acV7NvC',
 'modifiedTime': '2019-05-03T18:59:19.000Z',
'name': '~$ LENGUA PROG.docx', 'size': '162'}]
```

So you can delete all items that refer to a "temp" file like below:

```
for index,item in enumerate(items):
    if item['fileExtension'] =="tmp":
        del items[index]
```

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful.